# What does the output of \dt mean?

Tags: postgresql

```
postgres=# \c students
You are now connected to database "students" as user "postgres".
students=# \dt;
 public | student | table | postgres

students=# \dt+
 public | student | table | postgres | 0 bytes | 

students=#
```

What does the output of `\dt` mean? I only only know there is a table `student` under database `students` beforehand.

I am using psql (9.6.6).

Thanks.

Comment: some info is  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html

Answer (score 9):

`\dt` (no parameters) appears to list all the tables in the current schema, as the docs here explain: http://www.postgresonline.com/special_feature.php?sf_name=postgresql83_psql_cheatsheet

Your output is one row showing the (one) student table.  If I create one table, similarly, I get this:

```
 postgres=# \dt
         List of relations
 Schema |  Name   | Type  | Owner  
--------+---------+-------+--------
 public | student | table | postgres
(1 row)
```

Do `\dt+` to see slightly expanded information.

Comment: Thanks. But `\dt+` doesn't show any more information to help me understand the columns.

Comment: @Tim `\dt+` comes with a header that explains every column of the `\dt+` output.

Comment: @zerkms mine doesn't have a header. see my post.

Comment: @Tim right. So next time you ask a question it would be helpful if you posted versions of the corresponding applications you're asking about.

Comment: @zerkms I am using psql (9.6.6)

Comment: @Tim I presume the header given in this example lines "right up" with your output, doesn't that answer your question?  I suppose you could follow-up with a "why does psql not show my headers?" (try executing `\t` first, I'm not sure why they seem off by default in your case).